# How know if FMDB query succeeded

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I want to get any answer (for know if my query it was success or failure) of the following query:

```
let rs = try self.database.executeQuery
    ("insert into Practice(old, number) values (?, ?)", 
     values: [old, number])
```

but only i get this

```
<FMResultSet: 0x60000289ab20>
```

while i try iterate the collection, never into inside the cycle `while`

```
while rs.next(){
    print("never")
}
```

which is wrong in my code, why I get a clean collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `executeUpdate` when performing an query that updates your database, such as an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` SQL statement:

```
let sql = "INSERT INTO practice(old, number) VALUES (?, ?)"
try database.executeUpdate(sql, values: [old, number])
```

Needless to say, the way you know whether `INSERT` succeeded or not is whether it throws an error.

But `executeQuery` is only used if the SQL returns rows (e.g. a `SELECT` statement).

---

In the case of `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, an error is thrown only if there was an error during the update. But (especially if you have a `WHERE` clause), you may also want to examine `database.changes` to see how many rows were affected.